# printing statements with several forks

Tags: c, fork

```
int counter = 0;
int main()
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
      fork();
      counter ++;
      printf("counter = %d\n", counter);
}
  printf("counter = %d\n", counter);
  return 0;
}
```

When drawing the fork process im getting only 7 printfs on `counter`.

How come it (should) prints `counter` 10 times?

Thats what i have visually:

```
                      ____1____2__
                     |
           _____fork |____1____2__
          |     __________1____2___
          |fork|
          |    |
main__fork|____|_____________2_____  

The numbers 1 and 2 represent `counter` printed by `printf`. Could anyone explain this (visually would be great) ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting that each process prints an extra time right before it ends.

So, for example, the first process prints "counter = 0", "counter = 1", "counter = 2", and then exits the loop, printing an extra "counter = 2" before it terminates.

The code will be easier to understand if you change each `printf` to include both the PID and which `printf` it is.

> in loop, counter = 1, pid = 11755
>   in loop, counter = 2, pid = 11755
>   exit loop, counter = 2, pid = 11755
>   in loop, counter = 1, pid = 11756
>   in loop, counter = 2, pid = 11756
>   exit loop, counter = 2, pid = 11756
>   in loop, counter = 2, pid = 11758
>   exit loop, counter = 2, pid = 11758
>   in loop, counter = 2, pid = 11757
>   exit loop, counter = 2, pid = 11757

Comment: What i dont understand is why the first fork, for example, prints 1 and 2 and then one more time 2 after loop. The 2 in loop is confusing to me..

Comment: @ssss Well if you ignore the `fork()` call (or comment it out and run the program), you'll see the program prints 1 2 2, because that's what you told it to do.